# OpenGL functions give FunctionNotSupported error

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to make a 2D OpenGL project using LWJGL 2, and I am having trouble with basic rendering.

Main class:

```
public class ScratchCord {
private Renderer renderer;
public TextureManager manager;
private int i = 0;
private int i2 = 0;

private ScratchCord() {
    renderer = new Renderer(this);
    manager = new TextureManager();
    ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1240, 740));
        Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
        Display.setTitle("ScratchCord");
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, 1240, 740);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, 1240, 740, 0, -1, 1);
}

private void start() {
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        renderer.draw(i, i2, "ScratchCord/src/main/resources/textures/download.jpg", 200, 200);
        Display.sync(60);
        Display.update();
        i += 1;
        i2 += 1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.util.NoChecks","true");
    ScratchCord scratchCord = new ScratchCord();
    scratchCord.start();
}
}
```

For some reason, I get a FunctionNotSupported error, but the code works in http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d-4.html.
I tried setting the OpenGl version to 2.0, and I got an error in Display.create and the OpenGL context was not created.
I've heard that sometimes graphics drivers can break LWJGL, but mine are updated and other projects I have works.
Also some people say that the function just isn't in 3.2, and if so how would I do this?

Comment: You are explicitly requesting a core profile. Replace `.withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true)` with `.withProfileCompatibility(true)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your machine likely does not support Legacy GL, making it a "Core" context. Core contexts have deprecated legacy functions, like matrix operations, unavailable.

Find a tutorial that is for modern core opengl.